# Shunting Yard Calculator - Extended to negative, complex, etc

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, math-expression-eval, complex-numbers

This project is based off the shunting yard algorithm and has additional features such as negative value parsing. It's like a scientific calculator. I am looking to improve this project by getting rid of potential errors and optimizing code. I have tried many cases and have fixed the broken ones I've seen. However, although this works, I am aware that the code is quite messy and may potentially have bugs

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <complex>
using std::cout; using std::string; using std::getline; using std::complex; using std::abs;
using std::vector; using std::stack; using std::queue; using std::transform;
using std::invalid_argument; using std::map; using std::function; using namespace std::literals;
using std::isinf; using std::isnan; using std::cin; using std::exception;
 
typedef complex<double> cmpd;
 
constexpr unsigned int str2int(const char* str, int h = 0) //string to int conversion for switch case purposes
{
    return !str[h] ? 5381 : (str2int(str, h + 1) * 33) ^ str[h];
}
 
bool isNumber(const string& s) //check if a string is a number
{
   if(s.empty() || ::isspace(s[0]) || isalpha(s[0])) {
       return false;
   }
   char *p;
   strtod(s.c_str(), &p);
 
   return (*p == 0);
}
 
cmpd operation(string s, cmpd v1, cmpd v2 = 0, bool deg = false) //operations
{
    switch (str2int(s.c_str())) {
        case str2int("+"):
            return v1 + v2;
        case str2int("-"):
            return v1 - v2;
        case str2int("*"):
            return v1 * v2;
        case str2int("#"): //for negative powers
            return v1 * v2;
        case str2int("/"):
            return v1 / v2;
        case str2int("^"):
            return pow(v1, v2);
        default:
            return tgamma(v1.real() + 1); //factorial, technically it is a function but it is conveninent to treat it as an operator here
    }
}
 
cmpd func(string s, cmpd v, cmpd v2 = 0, bool deg = false) //functions, radians
{
    double toRad = acos(-1) / 180.0;
    double toDeg = 180.0 / acos(-1);
    if (deg) {
        switch (str2int(s.c_str())) {
            case str2int("sin"):
                return sin(v * toRad);
            case str2int("cos"):
                return cos(v * toRad);
            case str2int("tan"):
                return tan(v * toRad);
            case str2int("sec"):
                return 1.0 / cos(v * toRad);
            case str2int("csc"):
                return 1.0 / sin(v * toRad);
            case str2int("cot"):
                return 1.0 / tan(v * toRad);
            case str2int("asin"):
                return asin(v) * toDeg;
            case str2int("acos"):
                return acos(v) * toDeg;
            case str2int("atan"):
                return atan(v) * toDeg;
            case str2int("asec"):
                return acos(1.0 / v) * toDeg;
            case str2int("acsc"):
                return asin(1.0 / v) * toDeg;
            default: //acot
                return atan(1.0 / v) * toDeg;
        }
    }
    switch (str2int(s.c_str())) {
        case str2int("sin"):
            return sin(v);
        case str2int("cos"):
            return cos(v);
        case str2int("tan"):
            return tan(v);
        case str2int("sec"):
            return 1 / cos(v.real());
        case str2int("csc"):
            return 1 / sin(v.real());
        case str2int("cot"):
            return 1 / tan(v.real());
        case str2int("ln"):
            if (v.real() < 0) {
                return log(-1 * v.real()) + 3.142i;
            }
            if (v.real() == 0) {
                return INFINITY; //returning INFINITY for domain errors
            }
            return log(v);
        case str2int("log10"):
            if (v.real() < 0) {
                return (3.142i + log(-1 * v.real())) / log(10);
            }
            if (v.real() == 0) {
                return INFINITY;
            }
            return log10(v);
        case str2int("log"):
            if (v.real() == 0 || v.real() == 1 || v2.real() == 0) {
                return INFINITY;
            }
            if (v.real() < 0) {
                if (v2.real() < 0) {
                    return (log(-1 * v2.real()) + 3.142i) / (log(-1 * v.real()) + 3.142i);
                }
                return log(v2.real()) / (log(-1 * v.real()) + 3.142i); 
            }
            if (v2.real() < 0) {
                return (log(-1 * v2.real()) + 3.142i) / log(v);
            }
            return log(v2) / log(v);
        case str2int("exp"):
            return exp(v);
        case str2int("sqrt"):
            return sqrt(v);
        case str2int("cbrt"):
            return pow(v, 1.0 / 3);
        case str2int("root"):
            if (v == 0.0) {
                return INFINITY;
            }
            return pow(v2, 1.0 / v);
        case str2int("abs"):
            return abs(v);
        case str2int("asin"):
            return asin(v);
        case str2int("acos"):
            return acos(v);
        case str2int("atan"):
            return atan(v);
        case str2int("asec"):
            return acos(1.0 / v);
        case str2int("acsc"):
            return asin(1.0 / v);
        default: //acot
            return atan(1.0 / v);
    }
}
 
bool isOperator(string s) //checks if string is operator
{
    vector<string> v {"+", "-", "*", "/", "^", "#", "!"};
 
    return find(v.begin(), v.end(), s) != v.end();
}
 
bool isFunction(string s) //checks if string is function
{
    vector<string> v {"sin", "cos", "tan", "sec", "csc", "cot", "ln", "log10", "exp", "sqrt", "!", "cbrt", "abs", "asin", "acos", "atan", "asec", "acsc", "acot", "log", "root"};
 
    return find(v.begin(), v.end(), s) != v.end();
}
 
int paramamnt(string s) //checks parameter amount of a function
{
    vector<string> v1 {"sin", "cos", "tan", "sec", "csc", "cot", "ln", "log10", "exp", "sqrt", "cbrt", "abs", "asin", "acos", "atan", "asec", "acsc", "acot"};
    vector<string> v2 {"log", "root"};
 
    return find(v1.begin(), v1.end(), s) != v1.end() ? 1 : 2;
}
 
void newval(int n, stack<cmpd> &s, queue<string> &q, function<cmpd(string o, cmpd a, cmpd b, bool deg)> func, bool isdeg) //evaluates using either the operate or the func function
{
    if (s.size() < n) {
        throw invalid_argument("Error: invalid expression");
    }
 
    cmpd a = s.top();
    s.pop();
    if (n == 1) {
        s.push(func(q.front(), a, 0, isdeg));
    }
    else {
        cmpd b = s.top();
        s.pop();
        s.push(func(q.front(), b, a, isdeg));
    }
    q.pop();
}
 
cmpd evaluate(queue<string> q, bool isdeg) //evaluates reverse polish notation given by parse function
{
    stack<cmpd> valstack;
    const int qsize = q.size();
 
    for (int i = 0; i < qsize; ++i) {
        if (isNumber(q.front())) {
            if (q.front() == "3.142") {
                valstack.push(acos(-1));
            }
            else if (q.front() == "2.718") {
                valstack.push(exp(1));
            }
            else {
                valstack.push(stod(q.front()));
            }
            q.pop();
        }
        else if (isOperator(q.front())) {
            q.front() == "!" ? newval(1, valstack, q, operation, isdeg) : newval(2, valstack, q, operation, isdeg);
        }
        else if (isFunction(q.front())) {
            paramamnt(q.front()) == 1 ? newval(1, valstack, q, func, isdeg) : newval(2, valstack, q, func, isdeg);
        }
    }
 
    return valstack.top();
}
 
queue<string> parse(vector<string> tokens) //converts vector of tokens to reverse polish notation
{
    map<string, int> m {{"+", 1}, {"-", 1}, {"*", 2}, {"/", 2}, {"^", 3}, {"!", 4}, {"#", 5}}; //operator precedence
    map<string, char> assoc {{"+", 'l'}, {"-", 'l'}, {"*", 'l'}, {"/", 'l'}, {"^", 'r'}, {"!", 'r'}, {"(", 'l'}, {")", 'l'}}; //operator and parenthesis associativity
 
    stack<string> operate;
    queue<string> que;
 
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i) { //checking the vector of tokens
        cout << "\"" << tokens[i] << "\" ";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i) {
        string s = tokens[i];
        if (isNumber(s)) {
            que.push(s);
        }
        else if (isFunction(s) || s == "(") {
            operate.push(s);
        }
        else if (isOperator(s)) {
            while (operate.size() != 0 && operate.top() != "(" && (m[operate.top()] > m[s] || (m[s] == m[operate.top()] && assoc[s] == 'l'))) { 
                que.push(operate.top());
                operate.pop();
            }
            operate.push(s);
        }
        else if (s == ")") {
            if (operate.size() < 1) {
                throw invalid_argument("Error: right parenthesis at start of expression");
            }
            while (operate.top() != "(") {
                que.push(operate.top());
                operate.pop();
            }
            operate.pop();
            if (isFunction(operate.top())) {
                que.push(operate.top());
                operate.pop();
            }
        }
        else {
            throw invalid_argument("Error: invalid token");
        }
    }
    
    const int osize = operate.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < osize; ++i) {
        que.push(operate.top());
        operate.pop();
    }
 
    cout << "\n";
    queue<string> q2 = que;
    const int q2size = q2.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < q2size; ++i) { //checking queue here
        cout << q2.front() << " ";
        q2.pop();
    }
 
    return que;
}
 
vector<string> lex(string input) //tokenizes input
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; ++i) { //checks if a number is next to a function in order to multiply them
        if (isdigit(input[i]) && isalpha(input[i + 1])) {
            input = input.substr(0, i + 1) + "*" + input.substr(i + 1);
        }
    }
 
    string buffer = "";
    vector<string> output {"0", "+"};
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
        if (input[i] == '-') {
            output.push_back(buffer);
            if (output.size() != 0 && (output[output.size() - 1] == ")" || isNumber(output[output.size() - 1]))) { //subtraction
                output.push_back(input.substr(i, 1));
            }
            else { //negative val
                string a = "";
                if (output.size() >= 2) {
                    string a = output[output.size() - 2];
                }
                output.push_back("-1");
                if (a == "^") {
                    output.push_back("#");
                }
                else {
                    output.push_back("*");
                }
            }
            buffer = "";
        }
        else if (isOperator(input.substr(i, 1)) || input[i] == '(' || input[i] == ')') { //operator or parenthesis
            output.push_back(buffer);
            output.push_back(input.substr(i, 1));
            buffer = "";
        }
        else if (input[i] == ',') { //comma
            output.push_back(buffer);
            output.push_back(",");
            buffer = "";
        }
        else if (input[i] == 'e' && (input[i + 1] != 'x' && input[i + 1] != 'c' || i == input.length() - 1)) { //e
            output.push_back("2.718");
        }
        else if (input[i] == 'p' && input[i + 1] == 'i') { //pi
            input = input.substr(0, i) + input.substr(i + 1);
            output.push_back("3.142");
        }
        else if (input[i] == 'i' && (i == 0 || input[i - 1] != 's')) {
            output.push_back("sqrt");
            output.push_back("(");
            output.push_back("-1");
            output.push_back(")");
        }
        else { //number or function
            buffer += input.substr(i, 1);
        }
    }
    
    output.push_back(buffer);
    output.erase(remove(output.begin(), output.end(), ""), output.end());
    if (count(output.begin(), output.end(), "(") != count(output.begin(), output.end(), ")")) {
        throw invalid_argument("Error: mismatched parentheses");
    }
 
    for (int i = 1; i < output.size(); ++i) {
        if (output[i] == "(" && (isNumber(output[i - 1]) || output[i - 1] == ")" || output[i - 1] == "!")) {
            output.insert(output.begin() + i, "*");
        }
        else if (output[i] == ")" && isNumber(output[i + 1])) {
            output.insert(output.begin() + i + 1, "*");
            ++i;
        }
        else if (isNumber(output[i]) && (isNumber(output[i - 1]))) {
            output.insert(output.begin() + i, "*");
            ++i;
        }
    }
 
    output.erase(remove(output.begin(), output.end(), ","), output.end());
 
    return output;
}
 
int main()
{
    cout << "This calculator has experimental support with complex numbers.\n";
    cout << "3.142 and 2.718 are assumed as pi and e respectively (type 3.1420 for example if you want 3.142 instead of pi).\n";
    cout << "If the absolute value of a number is <= 0.0001, it will be rounded to 0.\n";
 
    cout << "\nRadians or Degrees? Enter rad or deg. (default is radians): ";
    string measure;
    cin >> measure;
    transform(measure.begin(), measure.end(), measure.begin(), ::tolower);
    if (measure != "rad" && measure != "deg") {
        cout << "defaulting to rad...\n";
        measure = "rad";
    }
    bool isdeg = measure != "rad";
 
    cin.ignore();
 
    cout << "\nEnter (use parenthesis for functions like ln()): \n";
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    input.erase(remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), ::isspace), input.end()); //removes spaces from input
 
    cmpd val;
    try {
        val = evaluate(parse(lex(input)), isdeg);
    } catch (const exception& e) {
        cout << e.what();
        return 1;
    }
 
    cout.precision(16);
    cout << "\nanswer: \n";
    if (isnan(val.real()) || isinf(val.real())) {
        cout << "undefined";
    }
    else {
       if (abs(val.real()) <= 0.0001) { //used a tolerance value here because for some reason sqrt(-1)^2 evaluated into -1 + a very small constant times i so...
            if (abs(val.imag()) <= 0.0001) { //lots of if statements for formatting purposes
                cout << 0;
            }
            else {
                if (val.imag() == 1) {
                    cout << "i";
                }
                else if (val.imag() == -1) {
                    cout << "-i";
                }
                else {
                    cout << val.imag() << "i";
                }
            }
        }
        else if (abs(val.imag()) <= 0.0001) {
            cout << val.real();
        }
        else {
            cout << val.real() << " + " << val.imag() << "i";
        }
    }
}
```

How would you improve this program?

Comment: Hello at Code Review@SE. Applying an unnamed tolerance to decide outputting `0`, but not `±i` without a numerical value looks paradox. Please explicitly state what you think *redundant* in the code presented for review. See [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for *why* a review needs context. Here I, for one, can't discern detrimental redundancy - is it in a repetition with code in some "outer else-statement"?

Answer (score 2):

Well, stop passing `string` **by value**.
Actually, use `string_view` for parameters (by value).
Why does str2int take a `const char*` rather than a `string` or `string_view`?  Again, just make it take a `string_view`.

`isNumber` does all the work of obtaining the number, just to throw it away (and presumably do it all over again when you do want the number).

I see what you're doing with `str2int`... you need to make sure you don't have a clash.  Really, you should tokenize the input as a separate step, then pass the token ID around rather than the original token as a string.

```
bool isOperator(string s) //checks if string is operator
{
    vector<string> v {"+", "-", "*", "/", "^", "#", "!"};
 
    return find(v.begin(), v.end(), s) != v.end();
}
```

again, **string by value?**
The list of allowed values should be `constexpr` and can be a plain array, not a `vector`.  Use `std::any_of`  rather than writing your own.

Every time you call one of these functions, it creates the vector from scratch!  It allocates the memory, and allocates memory for *each string* and copies the literal into it.  Then it frees it all again.

So use a `constexpr string_view[] = { ... };` instead, and it will all be fixed at compile time.  Furthermore, it will remember the length of each string (unlike using the `const char*`), but not have the space overhead of the `std::string` type.

`paramamnt`'s local variable `v2` is not used.

Answer (score 1):

Why are there so many `using`s at file scope?  That makes it a lot harder to see where identifiers have come from.  I'm sure the code doesn't need so many standard identifiers in global scope.

Here, we use `::isspace` without a definition (it's in the deprecated `<ctype.h>` rather than `<cctype>`):

```
   if(s.empty() || ::isspace(s[0]) || isalpha(s[0])) {
```

Not only that, but we're passing (possibly signed) `char` to a character-classification function.  We need to convert to `unsigned char` before its promotion to `int`.

`str2int()` is a confusing name for a *hash* function.  And there's a risk of your program failing to compile with a very unhelpful diagnostic when built on a platform where the character coding leads to collisions with the values you've used.  Which encodings have you tried?  I'm guessing only ASCII and EBCDIC?

It's much more reliable to just use a `std::map` to map strings to an `enum class` type - and this will help your compiler to warn about any missing `case` labels.